# How to write and rds file in foundry code repository

Tags: r, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I would like to know if there's an option to write an rds file to foundry file system from code repository. I know it's possible from code workbook but I couldn't find a way applying the approach in code repository.

In this example, I'm storing the lower_case object as foundry data table but I would rather store it as .rds file.

```
from transforms.api import transform, Output

@transform(
    output=Output("/Global/Foundry Training/Examples/PySpark & Python Transforms/Transforms Execute R Code/lower")
)
def my_compute_function(ctx, output):
    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
    from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
    from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter
    import rpy2.robjects as ro

    base = importr('base')
    # Calling functions example
    lower_case = base.tolower("LOWER")[0]

**    #What I need to to to write lower_case object as RDS file to foundry file system
**
    output.write_dataframe(ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame([[lower_case]], 'lower:string'))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. This is the adjusted code to write an RDS object to foundry filesystem using rpy2:

```
from transforms.api import transform, Output

@transform(
output=Output("/Global/Foundry Training/Examples/PySpark & Python Transforms/Transforms Execute R Code/lower.rds")
)

def my_compute_function(ctx, output):
    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
    import rpy2.robjects as ro

    base = importr('base')
    saveRDS = ro.r["saveRDS"]
    lower_case = base.tolower("LOWER")[0]

    with output.filesystem().open('lower.rds', 'wb') as f:
        saveRDS(lower_case, f.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write whatever format of files you want into a dataset.
Here's a link to the relevant documentation: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/unstructured-files/#writing-files

Basically you open a file in the output dataset filesystem and write to that file as you would from a non-foundry python code.